# How can I insert data from custom form in a Wordpress site?

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have created a custom form using HTML in a Wordpress site and I needed to insert the form data into my custom db ( Wamp Server using phpmyadmin). Where should I place the sqli queries for the same so that the data gets appended to my table in my db when Submit button is clicked. I'm running a local Wordpress site.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>insert data in database using mysqli</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
<h1>Insert data into database using mysqli</h1>
<div id="login">
<h2>New Client</h2>
<hr/>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Client Name  :</label>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Name"/><br /><br />
<label>Aadhar  :</label>
<input type="text" name="Aadhar" id="Aadhar" required="required"  placeholder="Please enter Aadhar Number"/><br/><br />
<label>Mobile  :</label>
<input type="text" name="Mobile" id="Mobile" required="required"  placeholder="Please Enter Mobile Number"/><br/><br />
<label>Company  :</label>
<input type="text" name="Company" id="Company"  placeholder="Please Enter Company"/><br/><br />
<label>Description  :</label>
<input type="text" name="Description" id="Description"  placeholder="Please Enter Description"/><br/><br />

<input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit"/><br />
</form>
</div>
<!-- Right side div -->


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where did you add this form  ??

Comment: Are you using any page template for this form ?

Comment: I added this form in one of my page using the editor. I am using a Theme called Twenty Seventeen.

Comment: On which page ?? Or did you added this code in any theme file ? please tell that file name

Comment: Please check my below answer and let me know if that working or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following Code on your theme function.php file.

```
function themename_add_new_data() {

      $name         = $_POST['Name'];
      $adhar  = $_POST['Aadhar'];  
      $mobile  = $_POST['Mobile'];  
      $company  = $_POST['Company'];  
      $description  = $_POST['Description'];  

      global $wpdb; 
      $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "testtable"; 
      $wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
                                'name' => $name, 
                                'adhar' => $adhar,
                                'mobile' => $mobile,
                                'company' => $company,
                                'description' => $description
                                ),array(
                                '%s',
                                '%s',
                                '%s',
                                '%s',
                                '%s',) 
        );
      }



if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) themename_add_new_data();
```

I have tested the form and function its working for me

Comment: are you using wordpress thene no need to add database name and password and also you need to change the table name. testtable is my table name

Answer (score 0):

on click of the submit button you can write the ajax call which can call a function written in the your themes functions.php file. where you can write a code to insert the data in your custom table. i recommend you to create a child theme so when you update the wordpress your changes will not reverted. tutorials for [creating child theme](https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/creating-a-child-theme-for-wp-twenty-seventeen) also for the ajax call you can refer to the below links

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/310213/how-to-call-a-php-function-from-javascript-in-wordpress

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242278/wordpress-ajax-url-for-function-in-functions-php